# What is $A^{31}+B^{35}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $AB=B$ and $BA=A$ then $A^{31}+B^{35}$ is?

(A)$A^2+B^2$

(B)$A+B$

(C)$A^4+B^4$

(D)$A^3+B^3$

My work

$AB=B \rightarrow ABB^{-1}=BB^{-1}$

So, $A=I$

Similarly $B=I$

All option seem valid to me :O

Comment: What if $B$ is singular?

Comment: Then $B^{-1}$ won't exist.

Comment: @user3767495: And so your entire argument breaks down ...

Answer (score 9):

You are given $AB = B$ so that $ABA = BA$. You are also given $BA = A$ so that $A^2 = A$.

From here $A^{31} = A$ is a friendly exercise.

For that matter, so is $B^{35} = B$.

Happy holidays.

Comment: So, these are idempotent matrices.But why other options are invalid?

Comment: The other options are not invalid. If $A^2 = A$, then $A^4 = A^3 = A^2 = A$. Similarly for $B$. Thus, all four options are equal. If you can only pick one though, I'd go with (B) as it is the "simplest" answer in some sense.

Comment: Thank you so much Guys :)